# Wrong generated column name in association resolution of embeddable

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping, embeddable

I am using Hibernate 6.2 on an Oracle DB in a Jakarta EE application. I have a few main entities and each of them have an onetomany association towards another entity which holds the descriptions in different languages for objects of this entity. I would like to define a superclass that will hold a generic description type of entity T and modify the onetomany and manytoone associations accordingly. So far I have the generic class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Description<T> {

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Embedded
    private DescriptionToDescribableRelation<T> embeddedParent;
...
```

The embedded relation between the parent entity and its description entity

```
@Embeddable
public class DescriptionToDescribableRelation<T extends ThingT> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private T describable;

    public DescriptionToDescribableRelation(T describable) {
        this.describable = describable;
    }
```

An example of a specific description entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO_DESCRIPTION")
public class FooDescription extends Description<Foo> {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "describable", column = @Column(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false))
    private DescriptionToDescribableRelation<Foo> embeddedParent;
```

and finally the parent entity of the above description

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer fooId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "embeddedParent.describable")
    private Set<FooDescription> fooDescrs = new HashSet<>();
```

Unfortunately when I am trying to fetch either Foo or FooDescrs like this `select f from FooDescription f` I am getting an incorrect sql from Hibernate. The sql I am getting is this `select c1_0.describable_FOO_ID (.. other fields) from FOO_DESCRIPTION c1_0`. I do not understand why is this column name being resolved instead of the one I specified in the AttributeOverride. Are there alternatives with a similar effect that I might have missed?
Thank you in advance.